# Is there any equivalent of na.rm in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

In R we can use `na.rm=True` so that our function will exclude na values.
What is the equivalent in the case of Python?

There is a column in my dataset called Route which has information about where the flight stopped like this 'BOM → GOI → PNQ → HYD'
The data is in string format, but this column has some nan. I have created a function to extract the in-between airports.

`train['In_Between_Stops'] = train.apply(lambda x: x.Route.split('→')[1:-1],axis=1)`

but this is not working as there is nan and this is the error it is showing

`AttributeError: ("'float' object has no attribute 'split'", 'occurred at index 9039')`

The output I want is to make a new column In_Between_Stops which have the in-between Airports like ['GOI','PNQ'].

Comment: For anyone who happes to know Python but not R, some more explation of what what should be excluded from exactly would lead you to an answer sooner.

Comment: i think it has nothing to do with R. The problem lies with splitting the string correctly inside pandas. Could you explain what exactly is the intended output?

Comment: @StupidWolf my code is getting me the output I want. I have tried it on an element of the column Route. The problem is that there are missing values present in this column which causing a problem.

Comment: hmmm you wrote "but this is not working as there is nan and this is the error it is showing".. how are we supposed to interpret this?

Comment: @StupidWolf The error is showing at index 9039 and I have seen the Route is nan there

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're using pandas if you're looking for some equivalents to R functions. DataFrame objects in Pandas will have methods which often have a `skipna` argument (like for instance the [`.mean()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mean.html) method). You can also remove NA values from the dataframe with [`.dropna()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html?highlight=dropna#pandas.DataFrame.dropna).